# A coin-tossing problem

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$, $n=0,1,...$ be a sequence of independent random variables with values in $\{-1,1\}$ so that $\mathbb{P}(X_n =1) = \mathbb{P}(X_n =-1)=1/2$, for any $n$. Let $S_{n} = X_1 + X_2+...+X_n$.

Question: How to verify that $$\mathbb{P}(\omega: \inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n(\omega)=-\infty)=\mathbb{P}(\omega: \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n(\omega)=\infty)?$$

In a textbook it says that this is obvious due to symmetry (yes, it's symmetric). But it's not obvious for me to get a rigorous argument.

Comment: Can you think of a natural correspondence between outcomes with $\sup S_n(\omega) = \infty$ and outcomes with $\inf S_n(\omega) = -\infty$?

Comment: @legionwhale So $S_n(\omega)=\infty$ is when the difference of +1 and -1 outcomes is going big as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But how to relate it with the measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\tilde X_n = -X_n $ and $\tilde S_n = \tilde X_1 + \ldots +\tilde X_n$. Now observe that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $\tilde X_n$. Due to the independence also the whole sequences $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(\tilde X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ have the same distribution. This means that also $(S_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(\tilde S_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ have the same distribution. This implies
$$\Bbb P \left( \inf_{n\in\Bbb N} S_n = -\infty \right) = \Bbb P \left( \inf_{n\in\Bbb N} \tilde S_n = -\infty \right) = \Bbb P \left( \inf_{n\in\Bbb N} - S_n = -\infty \right) = \Bbb P \left( \sup_{n\in\Bbb N} S_n = \infty \right)$$

Comment: It's clear to me. But I think it's better to mention why the distributions of the random variables $\inf_{n}S_n$ and $\inf_{n}\tilde S_n$ are the same also.

Comment: As measurable functionals of two random sequences with the same distribution they have the same distribution.